# Use property Created by Property Info and use in Lambda

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I have a method with parameter as object, the object is a string value of properties in `DocumentModel` class

```
 private PropertyInfo SortingListView(object obj)
 {
     return typeof(DocumentModel).GetProperty(obj.ToString());
 }
```

I want the `PropertyInfo` to be used in a lambda expression like below:

```
 var SortedDocuments=Documents.OrderByDescending(x => SortingListView(obj));
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions? Or any better way? Am I doing it correctly? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you're trying to sort your list of `DocumentModel` by whatever property is passed. The way you're currently doing it is wrong because you're actually sorting them by `PropertyInfo` of your property and since all objects are of the same type this basically does nothing. What you need to do actually is something like this:

```
private object SortingListView<T>(T obj, string propertyName)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj);
}
```

You can call it this way:

```
var obj = "SomePropertyName";
var sortedDocuments = Documents.OrderByDescending(x => SortingListView(x, obj));
```

If you're only going to use it here, you could also do it like this:

```
var obj = "SomePropertyName";
var sortedDocuments = Documents.OrderByDescending(x =>
                          typeof(DocumentModel).GetProperty(obj).GetValue(x));
```

This way you don't need extra method, you have all the logic inside your lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response let me go ahead and implement the way you said. Thanks for helping me out.